# Base class from Windows Service

Tags: c#, service, base-class

I'm trying to create a base class for a Windows Service. When creating, this is created automatically:

```
     public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
     {
     public class Base    //added this to become a Base class
     {
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)//generated code for Service
        {
          //a bunch of code here that I create
         }
     }
     }
```

And I Want to derive this class :

```
     public class Derived : Base
      {

       void Call(string[] args)
         {
            Call test = new Call();
            test.OnStart(args);///error says no suitable method found to override
         }
      }
```

The reason I want to do this is because this service will interact with multiple types of Databases and I want to have as much code reusable as possible, each one will have the same OnStart, OnStop etc... I've tried to use virtual, protected, public in the derived class. I can't change the generated code also.

How can I call the protected override OnStart? I will also have private members eventually and so I don't have to ask another question, if theres anything I need to know when calling those that would be helpful too..

Comment: Any reason you are creating an instance of `Dervied` inside the `Derived` class instead of accessing the `this` instance?

Comment: No that was just a brain fart, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit:
You have to inherit from `ServiceBase`.  Simply creating a public class inside the scope of Service1 does not create inheritance.  The correct definition is:

```
public class Derived : ServiceBase
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //example
        int x = 1;

        //call the base OnStart with the arguments
        base.OnStart(args);
    }
}
```

Then, inside of your Program class, you would create such harness to run it:

```
var servicesToRun = new[]
{
    new Derived()
};
ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
```

MSDN Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart(v=vs.110).aspx)

The protected OnStart method requires the argument `string[] args`, based on your code above.  You need to pass an array of arguments.

Comment: Ok so just so I'm clear on your answer, the "Derived : ServiceBase " isn't the one that is auto-generated, its the one I create, is this correct?